# How to consume a published OLP schema dependency?

Tags: maven, here-olp

This question is a minimum reproducible example based on the tutorial [Build a Batch Pipeline with Maven Archetypes (Scala)](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/data-processing-library/dev_guide/topics/quickstart-scala.html), though we are unable to consume a schema artifact in a pipeline we are building for a customer.

We have a separate repository we want to publish (`mvn deploy`) the schema from. We ran setup equivalent to (replace `djv` with your own unique string):

```sh
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes \
                         -DarchetypeArtifactId=pom-root \
                         -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 \
                         -DgroupId=com.example.djv \
                         -DartifactId=nodecardinality \
                         -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                         -Dpackage=com.example.djv.nodecardinality
...
$ cd nodecardinality
$ mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.here.platform.schema \
                         -DarchetypeArtifactId=project_archetype \
                         -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.13 \
                         -DgroupId=com.example.djv.nodecardinality \
                         -DartifactId=schema \
                         -Dversion=1.0.0 \
                         -Dpackage=com.example.djv.nodecardinality.schema \
                         -DmajorVersion=1
...
$ cat << EOF > schema/proto/src/main/proto/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema/v1/schema.proto
syntax = "proto3";
> 
> package com.example.djv.nodecardinality.schema.v1;
> 
> message NodeCardinalityPartition {
>   repeated NodeCardinality node_cardinality = 1;
> }
> 
> message NodeCardinality {
>   string id = 1;
>   uint32 cardinality = 2;
> }
> EOF
$ # <edit schema/ds/pom.xml per the tutorial>
$ cd schema
$ mvn deploy
```

## Primary symptom

In the OLP Portal, I can see my new schema in the list of Schemas. It explains that I can add a dependency on it like so:

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>com.example.djv.nodecardinality</groupId> 
  <artifactId>schema_v1_scala_2.11</artifactId> 
  <version>1.0.0</version> 
  <type>jar</type> 
</dependency>
```

However, I cannot download the artifact in the `processor` project:

```
$ cd processor
$ mvn install
...
[INFO] Building processor Direct1toN Batch Processor in Scala 1.0.0                                                                                                                                                
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom                                             
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom                                                         
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom                                                                                     
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE                                                                                                                                                                                               
...                                                                                                                                                                 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project processor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.nodecardinality:processor:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.example.djv:nodecardinality:pom:1.0.0 from/to HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT (here+artifact-service://artifact-service): Cannot access here+artifact-service://artifact-service with type here using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access here+artifact-service://artifact-service with type here using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout here -> [Help 1]
...
```

We see this failure only because we are running the `processor` project build on the same machine that we ran `mvn deploy` for the `schema` project so some files exists in the `~/.m2` cache. Without these files the download just fails:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                   
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                               
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                                                           
[WARNING] The POM for com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available                                                                               
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.jar                   
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.jar                               
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.jar                                                           
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE                                                                                                                                                                                               
...                                                                                                                                                                   
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project processor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.nodecardinality:processor:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0 in HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/) -> [Help 1]
```

## Secondary symptom

As we saw above, running `mvn deploy` from a local `schema` directory doesn't put everything required to build in the local `~/.m2` repository (that is, to build the `processor` sub-project). To put the required files in the local `~/.m2` repository we need to run `mvn install` from the parent directory (`nodecardinality`) of the schema repository.

This allows us to at least develop locally (temporarily).

## Partial resolution

Follow the instructions in the section **Artifact Service** on the page [Dependency Management · OLP SDK](https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/sdk-developer-guide/dev_guide/topics/dependency-management.html). Although the build gets farther, it still isn't able to pull the dependency:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------                                                                                                                                    
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                   
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                               
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT: here+artifact-service://artifact-service/com.example.djv.nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom                                        
Downloaded from HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT: here+artifact-service://artifact-service/com.example.djv.nodecardinality/schema_v1_scala_2.11/1.0.0/schema_v1_scala_2.11-1.0.0.pom (3.4 kB at 1.6 kB/s)                    
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1/1.0.0/schema_v1-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/schema_v1/1.0.0/schema_v1-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT: here+artifact-service://artifact-service/com.example.djv.nodecardinality/schema_v1/1.0.0/schema_v1-1.0.0.pom
Downloaded from HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT: here+artifact-service://artifact-service/com.example.djv.nodecardinality/schema_v1/1.0.0/schema_v1-1.0.0.pom (8.0 kB at 6.3 kB/s)
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_REPO: https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from OLP Public repo: https://artifactory.in.here.com/artifactory/here-olp-sit/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT: here+artifact-service://artifact-service/com.example.djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/djv/nodecardinality/1.0.0/nodecardinality-1.0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE                  
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project processor: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.nodecardinality:processor:jar:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.example.djv.nodecardinality:schema_v1_scala_2.11:jar:1.0.0: Could not find artifact com.example.djv:nodecardinality:pom:1.0.0 in HERE_PLATFORM_REPO (https://repo.platform.here.com/artifactory/open-location-platform/) -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

OLP Schemas are deployed to HERE Artifact Service. The service requires special authorization. In order to download a schema or java/scala binding you should include Maven Wagon in your project. Please refer to "Artifact Service" section in https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/sdk-developer-guide/dev_guide/topics/dependency-management.html

In short:

Add version of the wagon as a property:

```
 <artifact.wagon.version>1.6.1</artifact.wagon.version>
```

Add a placeholder repository to the list of repositories:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>HERE_PLATFORM_ARTIFACT</id>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <url>here+artifact-service://artifact-service</url> 
  </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Put the plugin reference in build section:

```
 <extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>com.here.platform.artifact</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact-wagon</artifactId>
    <version>${artifact.wagon.version}</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

Note that your need valid 'credentials.properties' file saved in `~/.here` directory. How to get it please read https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/sdk-developer-guide/dev_guide/topics/get-credentials.html

Best regards,
Dima

Answer (score 0):

The issue is deployment with a parent Maven project. See the last sentence of the last error in the question:

```
Could not find artifact com.example.djv:nodecardinality:pom:1.0.0 in HERE_PLATFORM_REPO
```

The `com.example.djv:nodecardinality:pom:1.0.0` POM was never uploaded when we ran `mvn deploy` from the `schema` directory. You cannot run `mvn deploy` from the top-level `nodecardinality` directory.

The simple solution is to remove the parent project pointer from the `pom.xml` in the `schema` directory before you run `mvn deploy`:

```xml
  <!-- <parent>
    <artifactId>nodecardinality</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example.djv</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent> -->
```